# Correct folders and conf settings for qgis-web-client with qgis-server?

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, apache, qgis-web-client

I have setup QGIS server using **[this](http://anitagraser.com/2012/03/30/qgis-server-on-ubuntu-step-by-step/)** guide sucessfully and would now like to setup qgis-web-client alongside it.

My QGIS server folder is: **/usr/lib/cgi-bin**

For qgis-web-client I have followed the qgis-web-client readme **[here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Web-Client)** and have cloned from github (as recommended) here:

**/home/web/qgis-web-client**

I am now stuck with editing the qgis-web-client.conf file to get things working correctly. I updated the path to "**home/web/qgis-web-client/site**" file. (See qgis-web-client.conf below for reference)

I think I am doing something wrong now and cannot understand the rest of the instructions in the readme. In particular:

> 1. Check the symlink in cgi-bin is correct.
> 2. Check the QGIS libs are in your /etc/ld.so.conf path
> 3. Copy site/index.xml and check paths match your system OR
>      Modify index.html and point your browser to that

Please can you tell me what is wrong with my configuration?

Please can you explain what the 3 points above mean?

Many thanks!

There seems to be many questions related to how to setup qgis-web-client and a lot of confusion. I have spent a lot of time scouring the gis stackexchange for the answer but so far have been unsuccessful!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
# Add an entry to your /etc/hosts file for qgis-web-client.localhost e.g.
# 127.0.0.1 qgis-web-client.localhost
ServerName qgis-web-client.localhost

DocumentRoot /home/web/qgis-web-client/site
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /home/web/qgis-web-client/site/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/web/qgis-web-client/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/home/web/qgis-web-client/cgi-bin/">
AllowOverride None
Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
#Uncomment the next line to enable logging to a file
#SetEnv QGIS_LOG_FILE /tmp/qgislog.txt
</Directory>


# optional rewrite rules

# Forbid direct access
#  RewriteRule ^/cgi-bin/.*$ - [F]

# Search with SearchPanel

# sample search on layer 'Hello'
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:.*)query=samplesearch&*(?:.*)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:(?:.*)&)?colour=([^&]*)(?:.*)$
RewriteRule ^/wms/(.+)$ /cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=/<path-to-qgis-server-      projects>/$1.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&LAYERS=Hello&QUERY_LAYERS=Hello&FEATURE_COUNT=20&INFO_FORMAT=text/xml&SRS=EPSG:4326&FILTER=Hello:"colour"\ =\ '%1' [PT]

# Rewrite /wms/mapname to qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=/<path-to-qgis-server-    projects>/mapname.qgs
RewriteRule ^/wms/(.+)$ /cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=/<path-to-qgis-server-projects>/$1.qgs [QSA,PT]
# Rewrite /maps/mapname to qgis-web-client main page. mapname will be extracted for wms calls in Javascript code.
RewriteRule ^/maps/([^\.]+)$ /qgis-web-client/site/qgiswebclient.html [PT]
# Rewrite /maps/* to qgis-web-client/site (e.g. /maps/gis_icons/mActionZoomNext.png -> /qgis-web-client/site/gis_icons/mActionZoomNext.png)
RewriteRule ^/maps/(.*) /qgis-web-client/site/$1 [PT]


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/qgis-web-client-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/qgis-web-client-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of blindly changing settings I realise that my issue was probably primarily to do with my poor understanding of apache2, virtual hosts etc.

1. I renamed the qgis-web-client folder to "map" and moved to: **/var/www/html/**
2. Updated my qgis-web-client.conf file paths:

path-to-qgis-web-client = **/var/www/html/map/**

path-to-qgis-server-projects = **/usr/lib/cgi-bin/mymapname/**

3. I can now reach my project at: `http://MYIPADDRESS/map/site/qgiswebclient.html?map=/usr/lib/cgi-bin/MYMAPNAME`

For some reason the map is zoomed in on Eastern Mali rather than the location specified by my project but at least I can access qgis-web-client - so I consider question answered

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this question/answer (78422)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78422/how-do-i-change-the-default-location-of-a-project-in-qgis-web-client) for information about getting QGIS-web-client to show your map and not Central Africa. Basically it's a bug/missing feature, there are only a few projections that QGIS-web-client supports and if your project is not in the default then it will not display your extents. I tried adding a new projection in *site/libs/proj4js* (NAD 83 / UTM) using the output from QGIS Desktop projection settings but it doesn't do anything. So you're stuck converting everything into WGS 84 / Mercator.

[How do I change the default location of a project in qgis-web-client?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78422/how-do-i-change-the-default-location-of-a-project-in-qgis-web-client)

Answer (score 0):

now the QGIS web client has an easy installer that will take care of all the paths.

Comment: Any chance there is a tutorial for this anywhere?

Comment: No luck with the easy installer :( It seems there is some conflict between references to 'qgis-server' and 'qgis-mapserver'

Comment: what sort of conflicts?

Comment: It says package qgis-server does not exist.  In installation of qgiS serveR package is qgis-mapserver

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/server_manual/getting_started.html#installation-on-windows